# Adobe EchoSign Embedded Widget Iframe Size

Tags: css, .net, adobe, echosign

I am noticing that adobe echosign is setting default minimum height and width using pixels while generating the Iframe for Personal Embedded widgets. I checked the below link (& other REST api documentations) and can't find a property to tell echosign to render the widget in a scalable mode according to width/height dimension of the device as in mobile, tablets or PC.

Api Documentation->
https://secure.na1.echosign.com/public/docs/restapi/v5#!/widgets/createWidget

Adobe EchoSign default Iframe Render setting->

```
<iframe src="******" width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" style="border: 0; overflow: hidden; min-height: 500px; min-width: 600px;"></iframe>
```

How to tell echosign REST api to dynamically adjust it's Iframe size?

Answer (score 0):

I tried finding a solution to this also, but the short of it is that it can't be done with their widgets. None of their internal settings or the API allow a way to modify the iframe styling.

What does work, however, is adding a little javascript and css to modify the iframe. Here's an example of javascript code you can use:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")[0].setAttribute("id", "echosignwidget");
document.getElementByID("echosignwidget").removeAttribute("style");
```

By adding an id and removing the inline style attributes you are now free to style the element however you please using CSS.

Comment: In my case since it was the only Iframe rendered in web pages, used the below and it seems to fix the width for various device dimensions                                         1.) On the master page /aspx $(window).on('load', function () {
            $("iframe").css('max-width', '100%');
            $("iframe").css('min-width', '');
        });                                                                                                                          2.)   Enclose adobe iframe in a div with width = 100% (https://helpx.adobe.com/sign/kb/forms-widget-resize.html)